# Get clicked button from Gridview onInit

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, request, postback

I have a gridview (default) with select buttons. Is it possible to get  on which button was clicked in event `onInit()` ? 
I tried to use

```
Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
```

but this returns only "GridView1". Thanks you for the answers

**EDIT**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="gridView" DataKeyNames="Nazev" DataSourceID="OblastiSource" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging">
                     <Columns>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Nazev" HeaderText="Nazev" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Nazev" />
                         <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
                     </Columns>
                     <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
                     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                     <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                     <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                     <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
                     <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                     <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
```

You should know, that DataField="Nazev" is the number I spoke about. In reality there is a M:N relation behind (I wanted to keep it simple for you).
I have two tables: "Towns" & " Streets". The gridview1 shows the Towns names. When the user select a town, I want to generate checkboxes with "street names". First the checked and add to Panel1 and then the unchecked and add to Panel2. Checked means, that the street is in the town.
So the town have lot of streets and one street have lot of towns (M:N relation). Do you have some smoother solution? I want to keep this structure.

Comment: I need to know information from row, where the button is, to dynamically create checkBoxes. If I will not do this onInit, then I cant later get control of checkBoxes.

Comment: You can, and you will :) And you can't do it in onInit. 'cos viewstate is not updated at this time, as I remember.. Or is it? Anyway, You may use OnItemDataBinding event and create and add as many controls, as you wish. But as far as for me, I would not use server controls. I prefer to use inputs and jQuery.

Comment: In the selected row, there is a number, how many checkboxes I will need to create. Can you please give some example, how your solution will work with my problem?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: you have gridview. Each row has a button. When button is pressed, the postback happens, and on server side you want to know which button (wich row) was pressed. Right? And render dynamicly a set of checkboxes inside a row...

Comment: I have a gridview (default), there is a number (how many checkboxes need to create) and selectButton on each row. When button is pressed, the postback happens, and on server side I want to know which button (wich row) was pressed. Then I need to create xx checkBoxes(depends on number from selectedRow) and work with them via findControl(checked or not). After all of this, there is a button "update", which will save the values of checkboxes to database. Hope you understand me :)

Comment: Can you post your gridview, please?

Comment: Yes, I need exactly the solution with postback. I have tried too to save the value of selected row to database (it is no problem for my aplication do it like this), but there is no event of gridview, which will save the value to database before PostBack, or am I wrong?

Comment: There it is in edited question

Comment: Yes, I've got it, that it is asp.net, 'coz it would be strange to deal with postbacks in winforms. :)  Well, what about sending ajax post to server with row number? when ajax is successed you may render your checkboxes on clientside and make a postback.

Comment: Well, it seams like it would be nicer to use ajax: you can request server, sending townID, and getting streets as a json, and render them on a client side.

Comment: Wow, that sounds great, but I have no experiences with ajax. Do you think you can send me example, how should I do it (put the townID)? Or some link, I dont even know, what should I type to google. Btw. Is there any oportunity to give you some stackoverflow points. I feel really thankful.

Comment: I am not in a rush for points, thank you :) Here is a link for a good start: [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-and-Receive-JSON-objects-to-Web-Service-Methods-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx).

Comment: when you are ready with json (you will get streets on client side), you will need to render them. For that, please read howto at jQuery page. For example: [jQuery append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)